Why does my Laravel process pool fails with the error: Unable to launch a new process
I have a collection of models that have a column with RTF content that was generated by third party software. I want to dislay the text version in a web application.
To do so, I am converting the RTF with a simple console application that use the vendor dll to do the conversion. I am using a process pool to speed up the conversion as there might be up to 50 models to convert.
Whenever there is more than 24 rows to process, I run into the following error: Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException: Unable to launch a new process.
I tried to chunk the collection into smaller batches and wait before a pool has done executing before launchng a new pool, it had no effect. Even if I do batches of 1 model at a time, it ends up saying the same error message. The logging shows that each pools are only ran whenthe previous has finished.
I also tried to send a signal to the pool and unsetting it, it gave the errors:
Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Process\PendingProcess::signal().
However, it should work as per the Laravel documentation.
Laravel signal documentation
Here is the latest version of my code:
<?php

namespace App\Collections;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Process\Pool;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Process;

class CommentCollection extends Collection
{
    public function attachTextComment()
    {
        $batches = $this->chunk(8);
        
        $pools = $batches->map(function ($batch) {
            return Process::pool(function (Pool $pool) use ($batch) {
                foreach ($batch as $comment) {
                    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "fr_CA.utf8"); // Ensure proper escaping of accented characters
                    $escapedComments = escapeshellarg($comment->Description);
    
                    if (!str_starts_with($comment->Description, '{\rtf')) {
                        $pool->as($comment->ID)->command("echo $escapedComments");
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    $pool->as($comment->ID)->path(base_path('app/Bin/'))->command("RtfToText/RtfToText $escapedComments");
                }
            });
        });

        foreach ($pools as $pool) {
            $results = $pool->wait();
           // $pool->signal(SIGINT);
            unset($pool);
            gc_collect_cycles();

            $this->transform(function ($model) use ($results) {
                $model->TextComment = $results[$model->ID]->output();
    
                return $model;
            });
        }
    
        return $this;
    }
}



It says the signal method is not available to a pending process. The docs do note that you have to run start on the pool before doing anything like this (so the processes are not pending but actually running)
